# Не выполняется код

Tags: python, python-3.x

В следующем примере необходимо получить результаты функции в зависимости от введенной переменной, но условие выполняется только одно. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем ошибка?

```
import math

x = float(input())
if x <= -20:
    print(math.sin(2*x**2+5*x))
elif (x > -20) & (x < 0):
    print(x**2-x)
else:
    print(math.sqrt(9*x**3-12*x+5))
```

Comment: Простите, не совсем понял, что значит выполняется только одно условие. Единственное, подозреваю, что строчка elif (x > -20) & (x < 0):, в которой & - это побитовое И, была задумана иначе)

Comment: `&` - битовое "и", вам нужен `and`. Плюс во второй ветке не обязательно проверять условие `(x > -20)`, т.к. если попали в эту ветку, значит числа `<= -20` уже отсеялись на первой проверке.

Comment: @Anton, выполняется одно условие, то есть, первый раз вводится значение х, и происходят вычисления, при последующих вводах значений х выводится просто х, а не значение функции

Comment: Не знаю, в чём дело( У меня этот код отрабатывает нормально. То есть, если запустить python3 file.py, где в file.py записано то, что Вы привели, то запрашивается одно число, его ввожу, мне выводится результат, на чём программа завершается

Comment: Вообще, то, что выводится просто x - похоже на работу в интерпретаторе, Вы не там запускаете код?

Comment: @Anton, все, разобрался, сам не так условие понял и все запутал
спасибо вам

Comment: Отлично) Рад, что разобрались)

Comment: @insolor: для булевых значений нет разницы между bitwise-and (`&`) и logical-and (`and`). `(x > -20)` лишние условие, но на результат это не влияет.